# Haskell type class instantiation

Tags: class, haskell, types

I am trying to set (PolyA a) and (PolyB a) to be instances of class Polynomial, where I want to implement coeffs, fromCoeffs, coeffsB, fromCoeffsB. I am not quite sure what am I doing wrong, because I receive an error message saying that my functions are not visible to the class Polynomial. Any help please?

```
class Polynomial p where

--default implementations
data PolyA a = Coeffs [a]
           deriving (Show)
data PolyB a = Const a | X (PolyB a) a
           deriving (Show)

--instances
instance Polynomial (PolyA a) where
    coeffs (Coeffs f)=f
    fromCoeffs f= Coeffs f

 instance Polynomial (PolyB a) where
 coeffsB (Const f)= [f]
 coeffsB (X f a)= coeffsB f ++ [a]
 fromCoeffsB [] = error "Wrong Input!"
 fromCoeffsB [f]= Const f
 fromCoeffsB lis@(_:t)= X (fromCoeffsB (init lis)) (last lis)
```

Comment: You have not defined any functions in the `class` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The following code compiles for me:

```
class Polynomial p where
  coeffs :: p a -> [a]
  fromCoeffs :: [a] -> p a

--default implementations
data PolyA a = Coeffs [a]
           deriving (Show)
data PolyB a = Const a | X (PolyB a) a
           deriving (Show)

--instances
instance Polynomial PolyA where
    coeffs (Coeffs f)=f
    fromCoeffs f= Coeffs f

instance Polynomial PolyB where
 coeffs (Const f)= [f]
 coeffs (X f a)= coeffs f ++ [a]
 fromCoeffs [] = error "Wrong Input!"
 fromCoeffs [f]= Const f
 fromCoeffs lis@(_:t)= X (fromCoeffs (init lis)) (last lis)
```

Summary of changes:

- Add methods to the `Polynomial` class declaration.
- Remove the type arguments in the instance declarations.
- Change `coeffsB` to `coeffs` and `fromCoeffsB` to `fromCoeffs` everywhere.
- Outdent the `PolyB` instance declaration by one space.

Comment: Thanks. The code is working perfectly fine, but now, when I am trying to run fromCoeffs [1,2,3,5] I get this error message: <interactive>:176:1:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘it’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’

      instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
      instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      ...plus three others
    In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’

Comment: @Vlad Give it a type signature, as in `fromCoeffs [1,2,3,5] :: PolyA Int` or `fromCoeffs [1,2,3,5] :: PolyB Double`.

Comment: Ok, Fair enough. Thanks so much for that! I programmed in Haskell for a year, but still don't know every little aspect of it. Thanks loads for your help mate!